# Competing Risks Likelihood in each State

Tags: cox-model, proportional-hazards, competing-risks

I have a competing risks model where every observation starts in state 0 and ends up in either state 1 or state 2.

I have the following cumulative hazard functions for each transition to state 1 and 2.

[image]

I am interested in finding the probability that an observation is in **state 1 or state 2 at time t**.

Currently, I write a for-loop where the observation starts in state 1 and then I use the hazard ratios to divvy up the proportion of the observation remaining in state 0 to either state 1 or state 2.  This seems cumbersome, and I was wondering if there's a closed form approach for this.

Comment: transition 1 and transition 2 means that they end up in state 1 and 2 respectively?

Comment: Is your question on just how to use R code? I think it's to go on stackoverflow.com but you need data and a reproducible example. No need to use hazard ratios or statistical models for what you describe; plus, they could be wrong. Use an empirical estimator instead.

Comment: @peteR you are correct

Comment: @AdamO sorry, I shouldn't have put R in the title.  I removed it.  It's more fundamental than code... It's "given that I have a discrete non-parametric cumulative hazard function for a competing risks model, how do I determine the probability that an observation is in state 1 or state 2 at time t in closed form"

Comment: @Joe is it a subdistributional hazard function?

Comment: @AdamO it is a cox proportional hazards model (coxph in R) with competing risks.  A semi-parametric model.

Comment: @JoeBass coxph does not actually handle competing risks. It treats "other events" as censoring events. The `cmprsk` package is what you're probably after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89781/discussion-between-adamo-and-joebass).

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop is basically performing numeric integration of the cumulative (subdistribution) hazard function which is exactly what you have to do to obtain time-specific risk predictions of event 0->1, or 0->2 or still being in 0 having occurred at a specific time.